# Need help to understand an Arduino Capacitance-Meter program

Tags: arduino, embedded, atmega328p, arduino-uno

There is a program for Arduino that without using any external component, measures value of an unknown capacitor in the range of 470pF to 18pF:

https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-make-an-arduino-capacitance-meter/

I tested the program on my Arduino Uno. The results are really accurate. But there are some ambiguities in the code .

The code implemented sort of an automated range check where after reading ADC value (`val`) there are two conditions, one is (`val < 1000`) for capacitors smaller than 1nF and the other condition (val >=1000) for capacitors larger than 1nF.

## Things I understand:

The second condition (part of the code after `else`) is almost clear. It is using the capacitor RC charging equation where R is the internal pull-up resistor of the atmega328 (`R_PULLUP`).

[image: rc circuit]

- Vs represents VCC of the microcontroller (`MAX_ADC_VALUE`)
- R represents GPIO's internal pull-up resistor (`R_PULLUP`)
- Vc represents ADC reading (`val`)
- t is measured in microseconds using `micros()`

By solving the equation for C (capacitance) we will get this relation:

```
float capacitance = -(float)t / R_PULLUP / log(1.0 - (float)val / (float)MAX_ADC_VALUE);
```

## Things I do NOT understand:

But the main ambiguity is in the first condition (`val < 1000`) where the capacitance is calculated only using ADC value (`val`) and **without measuring time (t)** and **without using the resistance (R)** of the charge circuit?!

```c
float capacitance = (float)val * IN_CAP_TO_GND / (float)(MAX_ADC_VALUE - val))
```

*Where did this relationship come from?*

It seems that the constant values of `IN_STRAY_CAP_TO_GND` and  `R_PULLUP` are calculated empirically. Despite searching through the ATmega328's datasheet, I was unable to find any information regarding the stray capacitance value (`24.48`) or pull-up resistor value (`34.8`) used in this code!

This is the circuit:

[image: circuit]

This is the code:

```c
const int OUT_PIN = A2;
const int IN_PIN = A0;
const float IN_STRAY_CAP_TO_GND = 24.48;
const float IN_CAP_TO_GND  = IN_STRAY_CAP_TO_GND;
const float R_PULLUP = 34.8;  
const int MAX_ADC_VALUE = 1023;

void setup(){
  pinMode(OUT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN_PIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
    pinMode(IN_PIN, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, HIGH);
    int val = analogRead(IN_PIN);
    digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, LOW);
    
    // ****** AMBIGUOUS SECTION ******
    if (val < 1000){
      pinMode(IN_PIN, OUTPUT);
        
      // Where does this relation come from????
      float capacitance = (float)val * IN_CAP_TO_GND / (float)(MAX_ADC_VALUE - val);

      Serial.print(F("Capacitance Value = "));
      Serial.print(capacitance, 3);
      Serial.print(F(" pF ("));
      Serial.print(val);
      Serial.println(F(") "));
    }
    // ******************************
    else{
      pinMode(IN_PIN, OUTPUT);
      delay(1);
      pinMode(OUT_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
      unsigned long u1 = micros();
      unsigned long t;
      int digVal;

      do{
        digVal = digitalRead(OUT_PIN);
        unsigned long u2 = micros();
        t = u2 > u1 ? u2 - u1 : u1 - u2;
      } while ((digVal < 1) && (t < 400000L));

      pinMode(OUT_PIN, INPUT);  
      val = analogRead(OUT_PIN);
      digitalWrite(IN_PIN, HIGH);
      int dischargeTime = (int)(t / 1000L) * 5;
      delay(dischargeTime);   
      pinMode(OUT_PIN, OUTPUT);  
      digitalWrite(OUT_PIN, LOW);
      digitalWrite(IN_PIN, LOW);

      float capacitance = -(float)t / R_PULLUP / log(1.0 - (float)val / (float)MAX_ADC_VALUE);

      Serial.print(F("Capacitance Value = "));
      if (capacitance > 1000.0){
        Serial.print(capacitance / 1000.0, 2);
        Serial.print(F(" uF"));
      }
      else{
        Serial.print(capacitance, 2);
        Serial.print(F(" nF"));
      }

      Serial.print(F(" ("));
      Serial.print(digVal == 1 ? F("Normal") : F("HighVal"));
      Serial.print(F(", t= "));
      Serial.print(t);
      Serial.print(F(" us, ADC= "));
      Serial.print(val);
      Serial.println(F(")"));
    }
    while (millis() % 1000 != 0);    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The unknown capacitor forms a capacitive voltage divider together with the stray capacitance of the leads and input pin.

When the output pin of the Arduino goes from 0V to 5V, this voltage divider will form some voltage between the two "capacitors", depending on the value of the two caps. In the real world, this voltage will soon drop due to any leakage, but sampling it quickly enough will probably give a good reading.

You could try running the simulation below. C1 represents the unknown capacitor, C2 represents the parasitic capacitance (which as you said, is likely determined empirically and would change a little with your setup), V1 represents the output pin of the Arduino.

This simulation gives an output voltage of 4.032 V. We can try that in the formula from the code.
4.032V would give a value of 3303 from an 12 bit 5V ADC.
So the calculation would then be
`capacitance = 3303 * 24 pF / (4096-3303) = 99.96 pF`

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYbzMm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The formula comes directly from the capacitive voltage divider formula $$V_{OUT} = V_{supp} * \frac{C_1}{C_1 + C_2}$$
and if we solve for \$C_1\$ we get this:
$$C_1 = \frac{C_2 V_{OUT}}{V_{supp - V_{OUT}}}$$
And in the above example \$V_{supp}=4096\$ which is the ADC value for the supply voltage (5V)

*(thanks to user G36 for the derivation of the formula)*

Comment: The formula comes directly from the capacitive voltage divider formula \$V_{OUT} = V_{supp} * \frac{C_1}{C_1 + C_2} \$ and if we solve for \$C_1\$ we get this:  $$C_1 = \frac{C_2 V_{OUT}}{V_{supp - V_{OUT}}}$$ And in our case \$V_{supp} = 1023\$

Comment: @G36 yep, of course it was that easy. Thanks! Added it to the answer.